# Get a field label for a given record Id

Tags: apex, record, label

Id recordId = 'xyz';
String objName = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

I found the object Name but I also want Label for this recordId.
How to use getLabel() on a given recordId?

Comment: Are you looking for the label of a field (one or more) on the related object (found from recordId)?

Comment: This object is having a field= "Name". Now every record will have different Name and its translations are stored in workbench. So I want the Translated Name of given recordId.

Answer (score 1):

Tested this in a developer org and as far as I know it only gives the object name

```
Id recordId ='00128000016pgdz';
String label = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getLabel();
System.debug(' label  is ' + label);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably faster, more efficient way to get this.

But here you go:

```
Id recordId ='001a000001hlaIHAAY';
Schema.SObjectType token = recordId.getSObjectType();
Type typeFromId = Type.forName(token.getDescribe().getName());
SObject sObj = (SObject)typeFromId.newInstance();
String label = Obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Name').getDescribe().getLabel();
System.debug('Here is your label, Your excellency : ' + label);
```